# Evaluate an ODE for several values of a coefficient and draw all the solutions in one plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to draw one plot showing all the solutions the following ODE with different values of `N`. How can i do it?

```
s = NDSolve[{2 y'''[x] + (y[x]*y''[x]) == 0, 
             g''[x] + (0.5****N***y[x]*g'[x]) == 0, 
             g[0] == y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[8] == 1, g[12] == 1}, {y, g}, {x, 0, 12}];

Plot[Evaluate[{g[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 12}, PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Note how I formatted your code - please do the same next time. Also: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 6):

`N` [**is a function**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) in Mathematica, so it is a bad idea to use it as a variable name. Let's use `m` instead. Define solution as function of `m`:

```
s[m_]:=NDSolve[{2 y'''[x] + (y[x] y''[x]) == 0, 
                g''[x] + (0.5*m*y[x]*g'[x]) == 0, 
                g[0] == y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[8] == 1, g[12] == 1}, {y, g}, {x, 0, 12}]
```

Set values of `m`

```
m= Range[.1, 3, .1];
```

and plot solutions:

```
Plot[Evaluate[g[x] /. (s /@ m)], {x, 0, 12}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[.8]], Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Or use interactive content:

```
alst = Plot[Evaluate[g[x] /. {s[.1], s[3], s[#]}], {x, 0, 12}, 
     Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[.9]], 
     Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotLabel -> "M = " <> ToString[#]] & /@ m;
ListAnimate[alst, AnimationRunning -> False, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi good point ;) done.

Comment: Dear Vitaliy Kaurov thank you very much. another question. if i want to assign to m specific value not in range between any number. for example m={0.7,1,2,20,10,100,1000} something like how should i write the code then?

Comment: @user4969 as you just did - define `m` as `m={0.7,1,2,20,10,100,1000}` instead of using `Range`. Btw I'd recommend choosing more unique name than user4969, hard to remember people this way ;)

Answer (score 4):

As it is already pointed out by Vitaliy Kaurov, `N` is a built-in function and should not be used as a variable. Besides, I'd like to mention new functions in version 9: [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) and [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html).

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{2 y'''[x] + (y[x]*y''[x]) == 0, 
       g''[x] + (0.5*m*y[x]*g'[x]) == 0, g[0] == y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
       y'[8] == 1, g[12] == 1}, {y, g}, {x, 0, 12}, m]
```

> ParametricFunction[<>]

For some given `m`, `s[m]` evaluated to ordinary `InterpolatingFunction`. So the plot can be written as:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[s[m][[2]][x], {m, .1, 3, .1}]], {x, 0, 12}, 
     PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range[.1, 3, .1]])]
```

[image]